# can't add item to my recycler view from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that has five fragments, One fragments is the notification fragment that has a recycler view where notification should be populating upon receiving them. now i have a function that add the items to the recycler view but when i try add it from another fragment it throws and null reference error.

**Here is the fragment where there is the recycler and function to add the items on the recyclerview**

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_notificationcict, container, false);



        notimodels = new ArrayList<> ();
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = v.findViewById (R.id.notificationsRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ());
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter (notimodels);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
}
 public void addItem(NotificationModel n)
    {
        notimodels = new ArrayList<> ();
        notimodels.add (n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted (notimodels.size () -1);
    }
```

**On the second fragment that adds items to the notification fragment**

```
NotificationFragmentCict fragment = new NotificationFragmentCict ();
NotificationModel model =   (new NotificationModel (R.drawable.logo, "OCApp", "Where are yiu.", "min"));
                                   fragment.addItem (model);
```

**Here is the Error**

```
rocess: com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp, PID: 27625
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemInserted(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.NotificationFragmentCict.addItem(NotificationFragmentCict.java:99)
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.AccountFragmentCict$4$1$1.onDataChange(AccountFragmentCict.java:374)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6803)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: U should communicate with one fragment to another fragment like below link... using interface  https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/fragment-to-fragment-communication-with-interfaces

Comment: thanks but the tutorial you suggested is for just sending data but my problem is accessing the recycler view from a different fragment and be able to add items from there @ArunAbimanyu

Comment: instead of creating a new instance of that fragment when u are adding item...hold references of that fragment globally ...and call addItem method from that refrences

Comment: could you please show me how am a newbie in android development especially fragments @ArunAbimanyu

Answer (score 0):

See This is Fragment A

```
package com.codinginflow.fragmentcommunicationexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private FragmentAListener listener;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button buttonOk;

    public interface FragmentAListener {
        void addItemsToFragmentB();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        buttonOk = v.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItemsToFragmentB();
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void updateEditText(CharSequence newText) {
        editText.setText(newText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof FragmentAListener) {
            listener = (FragmentAListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentAListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }
}
```

This is Fragment B

```
package com.codinginflow.fragmentcommunicationexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private FragmentBListener listener;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button buttonOk;

    public interface FragmentBListener {
         addItemsToFragmentA();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        buttonOk = v.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItemsToFragmentA();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void updateEditText(CharSequence newText) {
        editText.setText(newText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof FragmentBListener) {
            listener = (FragmentBListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentBListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }
}
```

This is an  Activity in which  u r going to add items to your recycler view

```
package com.codinginflow.fragmentcommunicationexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.FragmentAListener, FragmentB.FragmentBListener {
    private FragmentA fragmentA;
    private FragmentB fragmentB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        fragmentB = new FragmentB();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_a, fragmentA)
                .replace(R.id.container_b, fragmentB)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void addItemsToFragmentA() {
          fragmentB.updateEditText(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void addItemsToFragmentB() {
        fragmentA.updateEditText(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: so is what method exactly should i pass on my interface of the notification fragment

Comment: pass your values through interface like addItemsToFragmentB(NotificationModel notificationModel)

Comment: hey brother what to pass is now confusing me right now could you show me how  public interface NotificationListener
    {
        void AddItems(ArrayList<NotificationModel> notificationModels);
    }